# Sybase How to get dash separated date yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: datetime, sybase, sap-ase

I want to get date in such format `yyyy-mm-dd`, for example `2014-04-11`. But it seems there is no way to do this in Sybase (ASE 12.5) with the [convert](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm) function.

Currently, I get the date by 112 and add the `-` between digits. Any good way?

Comment: What kind is your sybase database? IQ, ASE, ASA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select str_replace( convert( varchar, col1, 111 ), '/', '-') 
from table
```

Answer (score 8):

Take advantage of format 140: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssss

Use char(10) to make Sybase truncate the string to just the first 10 characters, i.e.

```
convert(char(10), col1, 140)
```

Comment: I shared the documentation related http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/BABDBAHF.htm

Answer (score 0):

Look the table documentation shared by **Doberon**,  the table have all the formats. I try it and works nice:

```
SELECT convert(char(10),dateadd(month,-1, convert(date,getdate())),112)  from table;
```

My query format is yyyymmdd.